# MongoDB Mongoose Exclude Results from Query by Boolean Value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

**Edit**

I now realise I have two problems with my query.

1 (My original question):

In Node / Express I'm trying to filter results from a Mongo query by a boolean value. Should be simple enough right? Basically if the profile is not complete, I want to ignore the user.

This is particular part of the query which isn't playing ball:

```
{profileComplete: {$ne: false}}
```

I've tried swapping `$ne` for `$nin`, but this does't work either.

Am I getting something wrong in that query?

Here's the entire query, in case that's useful:

```
req.session.query = {$and:
  [
    {learningLanguages: {$in: req.user.spokenLanguages}}, // matches other users' learning languages with the current users spoken language(s)
    {_id: {$nin: [req.user.blockedUsers.split(","), req.user._id]}}, // disregard users who have been blocked by the current user AND the current user him/herself 
    {profileComplete: {$ne: false}} // disregard users who haven't completed their profiles yet.
  ]
}
```

2:

I've also just found out that blocking the own logged-in user from the results isn't working either. That's the last bit of this line of the query: `{_id: {$nin: [req.user.blockedUsers.split(","), req.user._id]}}`

Just when I though I was getting to grips with MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. It was working all along, but I had an if statement elsewhere (not very far away!) which was creating a different query. Doh!